# If session has value echo it else echo "all"

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables

**Update 2**

I'll just leave this here for future references. But this is the solution I created with all the help I got here. Thanks!

```
<script>
    function Refresh() {
        location.reload();
    }
</script>

<?php $number = $_SESSION["page_id"]; ?>
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['page_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['page_id'])) {
        echo do_shortcode('[RICH_REVIEWS_SHOW category="page" num="all" id="'. $number .'"]');
        session_destroy();
        echo ('<button class="btn btn-0001" onclick="Refresh()">Show All</button>');
    }
        else{ echo do_shortcode('[RICH_REVIEWS_SHOW num="all"]'); }
    ;
?>
```

---

**Update**
So I'm trying to just do a simple echo to see if the session is set using this code:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['page_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['page_id'])) {
   echo 'Set and not empty, and no undefined index error!');
};?>
```

But doing this breaks my page, I just get a blank page? How do I check if the session is set? When I do a echo of the session using this code:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["page_id"]; ?>
```

It does output the correct session value?? What am I doing wrong?

---

I have a sessions saved with PHP and I'm using this so that the page ID from Wordpress is echo-ed in a shortcode `do_shortcode('');`

This is what my code looks like:

```
    <?php $number = $_SESSION["page_id"]; ?>

    <?php echo do_shortcode('[RICH_REVIEWS_SHOW category="page" num="all" id="'. $number .'"]'); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode_all('[RICH_REVIEWS_SHOW category="page" num="all" id="all"]'); ?>

    <?php echo $shortcode ;?>
    <?php echo $shortcode_all ;?>
```

Now, what I would like to do is IF the page_id is not stored in the session it should echo `all`. So how do I go about this?

I found this code, and I think its something I need... But I'm not that great a programmer/coder...

```
<?php
$var = 0;

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}

// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($var)) {
    echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
}
?>
```

So, if I where to put these two together I would get something like this

```
<?php
    $number = $_SESSION["page_id"];

    // Evaluates to true because $var is empty
    if (empty($number)) {
        echo $shortcode_all ;
    }

    // Evaluates as true because $var is set
    if (isset($number)) {
        echo $shortcode ;
    }
    ?>
```

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: did you in fact start the session inside all pages using sessions?

Comment: Yes the session is started correct. The fist code in the opening post is working. It does echo the stored session variable to the correct shortcode. But when there is `no session` stored it shows nothing... that's why I want it to insert `all` instead of the variable IF no session is stored.

Comment: use `else{...}` statements.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Like I said. I'm not a coder. Is it possible to fiddle some code? Just to point me in the right direction?

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['var'])){...} else{ echo "session not set"; }` is the basic syntax to check if a session is set (or not). You could also add an empty `if(isset($_SESSION['var']) && !empty($_SESSION['var'])){...} else{...}`. There really isn't anything I can add to this.

Comment: so... did that ^ help you solve the question? you may also have to destroy the session with a logout method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm going to try it now. Hope that it will doe something. Yeah I already have a destroy button.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I updated my first post. I tried your code...

Comment: I see someone used what I told you to use. I was under the impression you'd invited me to submit it as an answer, seeing you accepted that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['page_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['page_id'])) {
   echo('Set and not empty, and no undefined index error!');
};
?>
```

What am I supposed to feel from the missing `(`?

Comment: Wow, I missed that missing `(`. Thanks. Now lets see if I can get this code to work properly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress then you should use the session_start(); in wp-config.php file so please first put in you wp-config.php at top and then check.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$number = $_SESSION["page_id"];

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($number) || $number=='') {
    echo $shortcode_all ;
}else{
    echo $shortcode ;
}
?>
```

Comment: condition explanation if you session is empty or if session exist but value is  blank in both condition all will echo else(otherwise) your page shortcode will echo.